# Subdomains and DNS

Tags: dns, subdomain

I currently have my own domain name and dedicated server and I offer different packages to my clients. What I want to be able to do is have them sign up with my website and create a package automatically that they can access via their username as a subdomain e.g.

http://yourusername.mywebsite.com

I currently have DNS entries set up for various subdomains with real information for my website e.g.

> Name  Type    IP Address
>   @       A   1.2.3.4
>   bugs    A   1.2.3.4
>   support A   1.2.3.4

However, if a new customer signs up at the moment I have to go and manually create an entry for them with their username in it.

I'm sure I've seen websites that manage to do this automatically, does anyone have any ideas how, or any other methods that I should be using?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details depend on which DNS server you're using.

One approach is to have some code that opens the DNS zone file and adds the desired records.  On Linux with Bind, you will then need to signal the server to get it re-read the zone file.

Comment: Ah, I see, so this is something that is done via the DNS server itself? I currently just use 123-reg.co.uk and point my nameservers at the entries they told me to. I guess they probably mask all of this work for me and as such I won't have much control over this? Thank you

Comment: Yes, the mapping between domain names and IP addresses happens at the zone file level in DNS, and subdomains are within a single zone file.  Some providers can act as a secondary DNS, where you provide a DNS server on the same machine as your web server, and they do periodic transfers of the zone file. With that in place, you can then point the central nameservers just at your host, so the local DNS server is used only as a source for the zone files, and not to resolve queries.

Comment: Right: you need to control in some way the DNS master server. Then, you have several techniques, editing the zone file, using DNS dynamic update, INSERTing into a DBMS, depending on the name server software you use.

Answer (score 8):

Since you apparently do not control the name servers, your choices are quite limited. One possibility is to use a wildcard DNS record:

```
*  A  192.0.2.1
```

where the star will replace every name. Not ideal (inexisting domains will also appear).

Comment: Very interesting approach. Other than non-existent domains getting sent to 192.0.2.1 (so the user gets a 404 instead of being given an error about server name not existing) are there any other disadvantages? Could it turn out to be more efficient than listing, say, 20,000 A records and having to restart bind each time one is added?

Answer (score 1):

With [Simple DNS Plus](http://www.simpledns.com), you can easily add such a DNS record through the included HTTP API. For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8053/updatehost?host=yourusername.mywebsite.com&data=1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Extra information: windows only, commercial solution with free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Since you apparently do not control the name servers, your choices are quite limited. Nevertheless, every **serious** DNS hoster provide you with a API (see for instance [Slicehost's API](http://www.slicehost.com/articles/2008/3/26/announcing-the-slicehost-api)). So, you may use this API and write a small program to update the DNS data.

(Foot note: handling paying customers when you do not even control the name servers seem... bad)

Comment: OTOH, getting a professional company to run your DNS instead of pretending you can do the job yourself seems... good ;-)